# Citrix Receiver on Lubuntu 14.04 32-bit

Tags: 14.04, lubuntu, 32-bit, citrix

I see that Citrix Receiver is currently available for Ubuntu 13.10, and there are threads about installing it on Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit. Is there any way to install it on Lubuntu 14.04 32-bit?

Comment: Well, I don't know what I did, but I re-tried installing the .deb from Citrix website several times and finally it was successfully installed! Now the problem is that it does not recognize the server address, while I'm sure I'm entering the correct address (which is working on Windows and Android). Is there any config that I need to change?

Answer (score 0):

http://support.citrix.com/proddocs/topic/receiver-linux-13-0/linux-install.html

It's not as simple as it should be. I can't get the Citrix Receiver Engine to always open the "launch.ica" file in Chromium, and in Firefox it is necessary to click the block at the left-hand end of the address bar and select "Allow and remember", but it's certainly much easier to get it running in Firefox.